# Inflection point of a cubic bezier curve and the complex numbers

Tags: c#, math, graphics, geometry, bezier

The general formula for calculating the inflection points of a cubic bezier curve looks this way: `X' * Y'' - X'' * Y' = 0` I analyze the code which uses complex numbers in the calculations:

```
private static bool IsRealInflectionPoint(Complex t)
{
    return t.Imaginary == 0 && t.Real > 0 && t.Real < 1;
}

public List<Complex> InflectionPoints
{
    get
    {
        var solutions = new List<Complex>();

        // http://www.caffeineowl.com/graphics/2d/vectorial/cubic-inflexion.html
        // solve X' * Y'' - X'' * Y' = 0

        var A = C1 - P1;
        var B = C2 - C1 - A;
        var C = P2 - C2 - A - 2 * B;

        var a = new Complex(B.X * C.Y - B.Y * C.X, 0);
        var b = new Complex(A.X * C.Y - A.Y * C.X, 0);
        var c = new Complex(A.X * B.Y - A.Y * B.X, 0);

        if (a != 0)
        {
            // quadratic equation: a*t^2 + b*t + c = 0 
            var t1 = (-b + Complex.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
            var t2 = (-b - Complex.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);

            if (IsRealInflexionPoint(t1)) solutions.Add(t1);
            if (IsRealInflexionPoint(t2)) solutions.Add(t2);
        } 
        else // b != 0, linear equation: b*t + c = 0
        {
            var t = -c / b;
            if (IsRealInflexionPoint(t)) solutions.Add(t);
        }

        return solutions;
    }
}
```

Here is the meaning of the basic bezier curve parameter:

- P1 - start point
- C1 - first control point
- C2 - second controls point
- P2 - end point

Could please explain meaning of A, B, C, a, b and c parameters ?
What is the role of the complex numbers in the above solution ?
Is it possible to find inflection points without using the complex numbers ?

Comment: Small code note: better not to copy over people's typos and just call your own function `IsRealInflectionPoint`, because the word is not "inflexion". You're just making it harder for folks to search for/through your code if you intentionally spell things wrong =)

Answer (score 1):

If you make expressions for the first and the second derivatives for X-coordinate (X', X'') and Y-coordinate of Bezier curve, then compose `X' * Y'' - X'' * Y' = 0` formula, you will get quadratic equation against `t` parameter with real coefficients

```
a*t^2 + b*t + c = 0
```

You can solve it in real numbers - treating only case when discriminant D>=0.

```
D = b * b - 4 * a * c
if D == 0:  //single solution
   t1 = -0.5*b/a
elif D > 0:
    t1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
    t2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
    and check range 0..1

private static bool IsValidInflectionPoint(Double t)
{
    return t > 0 && t < 1;
}

public List<Double> InflectionPoints
{
    get
    {
        var solutions = new List<Double>();

        // http://www.caffeineowl.com/graphics/2d/vectorial/cubic-inflexion.html
        // solve X' * Y'' - X'' * Y' = 0

        var A = C1 - P1;
        var B = C2 - C1 - A;
        var C = P2 - C2 - A - 2 * B;

        var a = B.X * C.Y - B.Y * C.X, 0;
        var b = A.X * C.Y - A.Y * C.X, 0;
        var c = A.X * B.Y - A.Y * B.X, 0;

        if (a != 0)
        {
            // quadratic equation: a*t^2 + b*t + c = 0 
            var D = b * b - 4 * a * c;
            if D==0 {
               var t1 = -b / (2 * a); 
               if (IsValidInflexionPoint(t1)) solutions.Add(t1);
            }
            if D >0  {
                D = Math.Sqrt(D)  ;
                var t1 = (-b + D) / (2 * a);
                var t2 = (-b - D) / (2 * a);

                if (IsValidInflexionPoint(t1)) solutions.Add(t1);
                if (IsValidInflexionPoint(t2)) solutions.Add(t2);
             }
        } 
        else // b != 0, linear equation: b*t + c = 0
        {
            var t = -c / b;
            if (IsValidInflexionPoint(t)) solutions.Add(t);
        }

        return solutions;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how the formula for calculating ```A```, ```B``` and ```C``` has been derived ? What is meaning of those parameters ?

Comment: You can get Bezier formula `P1.X*(1-t)^3+3*C1.X*t*(1-t)^2...`, find the first derivative against `t`, then the second derivative, do the same for Y-component, put all four expressions into `X' * Y'' - X'' * Y' = 0` formula, carry on all needed transformations to get quadratic equation. Perhaps one needs 3 or 4 fully written pages.

Comment: What is the role of the complex numbers in the above calculations ?

Comment: "Reality", mostly. By rewriting our terms, we may have created an expression that has one or more complex roots, so we need to make sure that the values are typed correctly to allow for that result.

Comment: Is it possible to find inflection points without using the complex numbers ?

Comment: Yes, possible, I've described the way. [School method to solve quadratic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation). a,b,c are real numbers, not complex ones. Quadratic equaion might have complex solutions, but we don't need them here.

Comment: Literally removed Complex stuff

Comment: Is it more clear now?